# Replace nan values in tensorflow tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working on a convolutional neural network in tensorflow and I have a problem. The problem is the input image I read through tfrecords contains a certain number of nan values. The cause of this is the image represents a depthmap which has some infinite values in it, and in the process of encoding it in the tfrecord and then decoding to feed it to the net these infinite values become nan values.

Now, since in my situation replacing the infinite values in the original image before encoding it in the tfrecors is not an option, there is any way I can replace the nan values in my image tensor as an operation to do before I feed it to the net?

Comment: I tried `input_clean = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x if x == x else 0.0, input)`, but it doesn't remove the NaNs... And this: `cleaned = tf.map_fn(lambda x: 0.0 if math.isnan(x) else 2*x, input)` - raises `TypeError: a float is required`...

Answer (score 37):

A combination of tf.where and tf.is_nan should work:

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.Session():
    has_nans = tf.constant([float('NaN'), 1.])
    print(tf.where(tf.is_nan(has_nans), tf.zeros_like(has_nans), has_nans).eval())
```

Prints (using TensorFlow 0.12.1):

```
[ 0.  1.]
```

Comment: Any faster option as compared to tf.where()? We are having to use this number of times in our codebase and tf.where is quickly becoming the bottleneck here.

Comment: I don't know of any fused op for this; theoretically you could write one, or maybe get [XLA](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/) to fuse it for you. Do you know where the NaNs are coming from? Ideally this shouldn't be necessary in very many places, if at all. [add_check_numerics_ops](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add_check_numerics_ops) or [tfdbg](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger) may be helpful for tracking them down.

Answer (score 11):

If someone is looking for the solution in Tensorflow 2.0, the adapted code of [Allen Lavoie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42044859/12066144) is :

```py
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.compat.v1.Session():
    has_nans = tf.constant([float('NaN'), 1.])
    print(tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(has_nans), tf.zeros_like(has_nans), has_nans).eval())
```

Answer (score 8):

Clip by value made NaN infinity and where was overkill for one variable. I used this to convert a single value to 0 if it's NaN:

```
value_not_nan = tf.dtypes.cast(tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.is_nan(value)), dtype=tf.float32)
tf.math.multiply_no_nan(value, value_not_nan)
```

Answer (score 7):

A much easier approach, compatible with TF2.0, is to just use `tf.clip_by_value`, which mirrors `np.clip` and removes NaNs (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7014)):

```
no_nans = tf.clip_by_value(has_nans, -1e12, 1e12)
```

Some caveats:
1) this also removes infs
2) Depending on your application you may need to set the clip value to a high value to avoid losing info.

Comment: What does it do with the NaNs? Map them to zero?

Comment: This doesn't work in tensorflow 2.8.

Comment: Doesn't to work with TF 2.7. NaNs come out unchanged

Answer (score 3):

In tensorflow 2.0 you can do it with `tf.math.is_nan` and `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update`:

```py
tensor_with_nan = tf.convert_to_tensor([[np.nan,1.],[0.,np.nan]])
new_value = 9.

indices = tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(tensor_with_nan))
tensor_without_nan = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(
    tensor_with_nan,
    indices,
    tf.ones((tf.shape(indices)[0]))*new_value
)
```

Comment: Cleanest way, in my opinion. Made my day!