# Impute missing values in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I know about `sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer` but does Tensorflow have built-in functions to do this as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case your imputation cannot be the same for all entries as suggested before, you may want to use [`tensorflow-transform`](https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/).

For example, if you want to use the mean or the median as the value to impute for the missing values in the corresponding entries, you can not do so with a default one as such values are dynamic and depend on the whole dataset (or a subset depending on your needs/rules).

Check out one of the [examples](https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/blob/master/examples/simple_example.py) on how you would do that in the official repository.

Comment: I don't actually find any examples of this on [the link you shared](https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/blob/master/examples/simple_example.py), maybe it's somewhere else? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't a handy function that does the same thing as `sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer`.

There are a few ways of dealing with missing values using built-in functions:

1. While reading in data: For example, you can set the default value for a missing value when [reading in a CSV](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/decode_csv) using the `record_defaults` field.
2. If you have the data already: You can replace the nans using `tf.where` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42044859/8581827))