# Tensorflow sum up on given indexes

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to get the difference in two matrices, so that I could define my loss function.  The model is very simple, I have one input matrix and one output matrix.

**Define X as the input matrix**

**Define Y as the output matrix**

Normally I would do a `tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(X-Y))` but that is not possible since the **matrix X contains nan values**.

So what I want do is add up X where `False` is given by `tf.is_nan(X)`, then I will add up Y at the same indices I added up X. Then I will define my loss as such `loss = tf.abs(reduce_nan_sum(X)-reduce_nan_sum(Y))`

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run(tf.is_nan(X), feed_dict={X: vals}))

[[False, False,  True],
 [False,  True, False]]
```

## Sample X and Y values

```
X = [[0.,  1.,  nan],
    [2.,  nan, 0.5]]

Y = [[0.002,  0.967,  0,2],
    [1.956,  0.3, 0.487]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NaNs can be replaced with zeros for the operation. Using the same solution as [Replace nan values in tensorflow tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043488/replace-nan-values-in-tensorflow-tensor)

```
sess.run(tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(tf.where(tf.is_nan(x), tf.zeros_like(x), x)-y)))
```